# How to loop in PostGIS to add the next lat long to a route

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, pgrouting, loop

I want to loop over the results of a query and then pass `row(n)`'s `longitude, latitude` and `row(n+1)`'s `longitude and latitude` to another function.

I have a query which returns a set of coordinates from a way-point table with no geometry field.

```
SELECT longitude, latitude FROM way-points ORDER BY date
```

I am also using the pgRouting extension and I have replicated the [`pgr_fromAtoB` function](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html) to allow me to generate a route between two coordinates.

Essentially, I have a table of waypoints (GPS lat/lon) and a separate table of roads. I need to get each GPS lat/lon, then get the road (or roads) that make up the route to the next waypoint.

My idea is for each waypoint pair (row(n) origin, row(n+1) destination) in the waypoint query, call the pg_Routing function to find the nearest road vertices's (NNS), then route between the two.

All I have to do is pass the input: `x1,y1,x2,y2` and I get back the list of geometries.

```
SELECT geom FROM pgr_fromAtoB('road_table',-122.662,45.528,-122.684,45.514);
```

Ideally I would like to have this automated so that instead of specifying the values of `x1,y1,x2,y2` I can just use a SELECT query that returns the coordinates.

So maybe something like:

```
BEGIN
-- Generate x1, y1, x2, y2

-- Set origin and remember start point
    x1 := 0;
    y1 := 0;

    FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM waypoints WHERE user_id = 5 ORDER BY waypoint_timestamp'
    LOOP
    -- first iteration sets x1, y1
    IF ( x1 = 0 AND y1 = 0 ) THEN
        x1 := rec.longitude;
        y1 := rec.latitude;
        geom1 := rec.geom;
    ELSE
        -- If the origin and destination geom are the same don't route
        IF geom1 = rec.geom THEN

        ELSE
            -- geoms are different so furuther iterations set x2, y2
            x2 := rec.longitude;
            y2 := rec.latitude;
            -- call the pgr_fromAtoB function (road table hard coded)
            EXECUTE 'SELECT ST_Union(f.geom) FROM pgr_fromatob(''roads''' || ',' || x1 || ',' || y1 || ',' || x2 || ',' || y2 || ') AS f' INTO geom;
            -- now set our new start point equal to the previous destination 
            x1 := x2;
            y1 := y2;
        END IF;

        RETURN NEXT;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
```

Do you know how to write loops in SQL and can help me refactor this into something that actually performs well in PostGIS?

Perhaps you know a faster way to do this without loops. Performance is my biggest consideration.

Comment: Are the lat/lon values also coming from road_table, ie, do you want a route from all points to all other points. There are other ways to set this up without using a plpgsql loop, which will probably be more efficient. If you want to do each row to each row +1, you can write something like `with offseter (id1, id2, geom1, geom2) as (select t.id, t1.id, t.geom, t1.geom from points t inner join points t1 on t.id = t1.id + 1)`, pass this to pgr_fromAtoB and use the result in an update query. I didn't post an answer, because I'm not totally clear on your set up, but I can if you clarify.

Comment: Just to be clear, the loop approach will work, but will likely be much slower.

Comment: What do you think about lead window function to get next row @John Barça ?

Comment: @josehermosillarodrigo, yeah, lead is essentially the same as what I'm suggesting, offset by one, but more sophisticated. thanks for that :D

Comment: @JohnBarça my lat/lon vales are coming from a non-spatial table (i.e. no point geometry).

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo If there is a faster option to loops, I am interested.

Comment: OK, but are you looking for a route from all lat/lon points to all others, or is it row x to rox x+1, etc. I was going to write up a query for you, but I need to be clear on the approach.

Comment: Also, having and spatial indexed geometry colum won't become queries faster than simple lat/lon colums?

Comment: @JohnBarça I think he want row x to row x + 1 in order to create "parts" of the route.

Comment: You are both right. I have a series of waypoints in a table. The first waypoint is the origin (A) and next waypoint (B) allows me to call pgRouting to route from A->B. Then I use B as origin and C as destination in order to generate a route from B->C. By the end I should have a route from A->B->C->...Z or row(n)->row(n+1)->row(n+2)...row(n+x)

@JoseHermosillaRodrigo with regard to spatial index, unfortunately the table is only lat/long, so I have to make geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your own function in PostgreSQL like this (Example taken from the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)) :

```
CREATE TABLE foo (fooid INT, foosubid INT, fooname TEXT);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2, 'three');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (4, 5, 'six');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_foo() RETURNS SETOF foo AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r foo%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN
        SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid > 0
    LOOP
        -- can do some processing here
        RETURN NEXT r; -- return current row of SELECT
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM get_all_foo();
```